# How can I improve performance of my multi-threaded python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent, gil

I make a python program that periodically (interval of 1 secs) grabs some data from ~700 files and queries to a server with the grabbed data. For a single query response time is about 2 ~ 3 msecs usually, but for some case it could take up to 200 msecs. The program consists of:

1. One extracting thread: every 1 sec iterates over 700 files, grabs data then dispatches grabbed data to a shared queue of a so called query pool.
2. A pool of N threads: each thread picks data from the shared queue and sends query to the server.

With N being 4 the program shows the best performance. If I increase N being 8 then the performance degrades significantly. I guess this is because of GIL of python.

Most of time the program works well but if there is a query that takes much time (due to late responding from the server) then the whole followed queries are dramatically affected.

I really want to take advantage of threading so I have been looking at `gevent` but not sure if it may help.

My questions:

1. How does my current design look like? Is there a better design for it?
2. Will `gevent` help in this problem?

Comment: When "there is a query that takes much time"... did you troubleshoot/debug on exactly 'what' is taking the time ? ... e.g. build up the connection prior to query, submit of query, the response of query... and-so-on-so-forth. Just "a query is slow" is probably not going to get you usable answers. What I am saying is; your "perceived slowness" may not be python, it might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, it looks like unclear. You should first figure out where is the bottleneck.

If I understand properly, every 1 second your extracting thread add 700 tasks into queue, and then every work thread just take one of these tasks and send a request to a remote server. Am I right?

In this case, does the network cause slow down? Could you confirm it? If you think `GIL` leads to poor performance when using more threads, does that mean there is some calculation bottleneck in your program?

And then for your second question, `gevent` will help you a lot if the slow down is caused by network.

Comment: While the task queue is not empty: every work thread just picks one task and sends a request to a remote server. In my test, once work thread receives a result then it just simply discards it so I don't think there is a calculation bottleneck here. The response time depends on the server since it has to do something with the data on a big set.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using GIPC https://gehrcke.de/gipc/ as a way to avoid the GIL and take advantage of multiple CPU's, and yet still retain cross communication.